# How to make a dataframe from character string

Tags: database, string, r, substring, data-manipulation

I have a long character string (800 variables * 100 cases) shortened for simplicity (3 variables * 4 cases) which I need to make a dataframe from;

```
c("eriomo", "1", "r", ".", ".", "erioscue", "100", "r", ".", ".", "fantastic code", "4", "r", "100", "r-1")
```

I am new to r and have searched extensively for answers but to no avail, and so I apologize if this is hard to follow or worded with the wrong technical jargon. - Before anyone asks, this is a particularly unfriendly output from a classification program and normally I would read in from a well formatted csv. Is there a quick way to get the data to look like this;

"eriomo"        "erioscue"              "fantastic code"

=> The variables above (all have 4 or more characters)

“1r”            “100 r”            “4 r”

=> one line of cases to corresponding variables

=> Is it possible to merge two of the cases into one column under each corresponding variable

“..”              “..”           “100 r-1”

=> process continues until 2 cases are made (if two cases are merged) or 4 cases (if not merged)

All of the 'cases' which fill the gap from one variable to the next belong to the former (preceding) variable.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated,
J

Comment: It's a bit tricky to understand what you wish to achieve. Especially the two last paragraphs are cryptic. I think it would help if you also posted the desired output, possibly using an even smaller example (fewer cases), which makes it easier to spot the 'rules' used for transforming input to output. Thanks.

Comment: Very sorry Henrik I have just noticed that the structure of the original question changes when you upload it. It is now amended and I hope that this has made it easier to interpret. Below is a partial answer which should now clarify the rules used for transforming the input and output. Thanks in advance for having a look at my question. J

Comment: @JamieT I still cannot understand what you want the final output to look like. Please post the data frame that you expect to get out of your simpler example.

Comment: Sorry mate not sure how to do this without the format changing to something far more confusing (I have spent much time trying with this). If you follow the code from josilber you will have a df that comes very close to what I am after

Answer (score 1):

I had some trouble following your description of what you wanted, but is this what you're looking for? I stored the vector you provided in variable `dat`.

```
mat <- matrix(dat, ncol=3)
header <- mat[1,]
df <- data.frame(mat[-1,])
names(df) <- header
```

At the end, `df` is a data frame with 3 variables and 44 observations.

Comment: Thanks Josilber - this has worked very well and I am sorry that the question was hard to interpret. I have shortened the example posted above. Do you know if it is now possible to combine row 1 and 2 in the same column for each of the variables